# Convert String of JSON into JS Object

Tags: javascript

I am getting this from form `"{ "format": "Tabloid", "orientation": "landscape"}"`

I want to convert it into as follow
`'{ "format": "Tabloid", "orientation": "landscape"}'`

Then I can perform

```
  JSON.parse('{ "format": "Tabloid", "orientation": "landscape"}') => Object
```

Any suggestion any other way to convert into JS Object?

[image]

Comment: That's the right way to do it. Why would you like/need to do any other way? You could theoretically write your own parser, but I'm curious what your motivation might be.

Comment: Okay So I have one form with text area in which user can add JSON, in backend I am getting this Sting of JSON `"{"format": "abc"}"` its not getting parsed by `JSON.parse`

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. If you have the data in the form you say you do, in JavaScript source code, then you'd throw an exception and the string will never be created.

Comment: Why is the user adding JSON that has enclosing quotes?

Comment: Your data doesn't have quotes around it. Your UI is just using them to tell you it is a string.

Comment: I have attached screenshot, basically user is only adding `{"abc": 1}` , when form is submit ed in backend node I am getting this as string enclosed

Comment: @V.G Sure, you'd have to do another round of parse on the value of that textarea. If your form is like this: `form = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "{\"a\":\"hello\",\"b\":\"world\"}"}` then you'd need to do something like `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(form).key2)` to turn the `string` value of your `key2` into `object`. Also what's your backend? I'm assuming Node?

Comment: OP, have you actually tried to parse the JSON and it's failed, or are you  making an assumption that it can't be parsed because of those quotes?

Comment: @V.G It might be helpful if you include your front-end (html + javascript) and back-end code (whatever language/server) in your question.

Comment: Actually doing JSON.parse on options worked before that when I tried their was some typo in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot I can see that `options` is already JSON. All you need to do is:

```
let obj = JSON.parse( options );
```

Don't worry about the `"` around it that the chrome console shows. Those are just because the console is informing you that `options` is a string, but they are not part of that string.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, there was some typo before when I tried to convert options into obj